# Clearing the suggested edits queue leads to -1 suggested edits pending

Tags: bug, status-completed, suggested-edits

Anytime I clear out the final suggested edit from the queue, the little notification up at the top of the page informs me that there are negative suggested edits remaining.

[image: Wat]

I've encountered this on three separate occasions today, so I figured it's a reproducible bug that deserves a meta post.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/133602/should-it-be-possible-to-have-a-negative-number-of-suggested-edits-in-the-queue

Answer (score 1):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

The number of reviews are no longer shown, so this bug is no longer apparent. Instead, we have grey and red notification dots to indicate pending reviews:

[image: grey dots on review queues]

When the queues start to get busy, a red notification dot will be shown on the top bar as well:

[image: red dot on top bar]